# Python Displaying 12-bit .tif image using Skimage and PyQt5

Tags: python, user-interface, image-processing

I am struggling with my Python code which I am pretty new in and getting really frustrated.

So what I am trying to do is create and GUI app for image processing. So far I am unsuccessful in making the first step that is to import and display my data, which are a 12-bit images. Here is the code I am working with right now:

```
import sys
import numpy
import PyQt5
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QWidget, QLabel, QFileDialog, QAction
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QPixmap, QImage
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from skimage.util import img_as_uint, img_as_ubyte, img_as_int
import skimage.filters
import skimage.io
import skimage.morphology
import skimage.exposure


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        menubar = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('File')
        editMenu = menubar.addMenu('Edit')
        self.resize(500, 500)

        dlg = QFileDialog(self)       
        openAction = QAction('Open Image', self)  
        openAction.triggered.connect(self.openImage) 
        fileMenu.addAction(openAction)

        closeAction = QAction('Exit', self)  
        closeAction.triggered.connect(self.close) 
        fileMenu.addAction(closeAction)
        self.label = QLabel()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.label)



    def openImage(self):
    imagePath, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()
    img1 = skimage.io.imread(imagePath)
    print(img1.dtype)
    img = skimage.exposure.rescale_intensity(img1, in_range='uint12')
    print(img.dtype)
    img_u = QImage(img.data, img.shape[1], img.shape[0],img.strides[0], QImage.Format_RGB444)
    pixmap = QPixmap.fromImage(img_u)
    self.label.setPixmap(pixmap)
    self.resize(pixmap.size())
    self.adjustSize()

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MainWindow()
    win.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

I am in fact able to display the image, but it doesn't seems to be display correctly for some reason. Here is the image I am working with: https://files.fm/f/yu9vxe6s

I will be very glad for any help!

Comment: You seem to be making life difficult for yourself! Have you tried getting started with more normal 8-bit images? Does your code work for that case?

Comment: I was able to display 8-bit image, but not .tif, it was simple .jpg, but with different code. For some reason I am not really able to make it work when loafing with skimage and then trying to use the QImage, maybe I am using wrong format, or it's just not the way.

Comment: The image you have shared is not a 12-bit image. It is an 8-bit palettised (indexed) image with 98 unique shades of grey.

Comment: I can see that the website I uploaded the image to compress the file - here is a new link, that should work: https://files.fm/f/yu9vxe6s @MarkSetchell

Comment: Your image is a single channel (greyscale) 12-bit image but you seem to be creating the `QImage` with `RGB444` which is a 3-channel RGB image of 4-bits per channel. I think you need to use `QImage::Format_Grayscale16` in place of `RGB444`.